# Methods execute in wrong order

Tags: jsf, jstl

Methods in xhtml are supposed to run in hierarchical order.

`cursoAlumnoView.listarEntrega()` runs first, then all methods listed above it.

```html
<c:forEach items="#{cursoAlumnoView.listaCursoAlumno()}" var="cur">
    #{cursoAlumnoView.setIdusu(cur.idUsuario)}
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td>#{cur.idUsuario.idUsuario}</td>
        <td>#{cur.idUsuario.nombres} #{cur.idUsuario.apellidos}</td>
        <td>
            #{cursoAlumnoView.devolverPromedioLista()}
        </td>
        
        
        <c:forEach items="#{cursoAlumnoView.listarEntrega()}" var="c">
            <c:if test="#{c.nota lt 6}">
                <td class="table-danger">
                    #{c.nota}
                </td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="#{c.nota ge 6}">
                <td class="table-success">
                    #{c.nota}
                </td>
            </c:if>

        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="#{actividadView.listaCursoAsignatura().size() gt cur.idUsuario.entregaActividadCollection.size()}">
            <c:forEach begin="1" end="#{actividadView.listaCursoAsignatura().size() - cur.idUsuario.entregaActividadCollection.size()}">
                <td class="table-danger">0.0</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `cursoAlumnoView.listaCursoAlumno()` this line has to run first otherwise the inner forEach loop wouldn't be called inside a iteration of the outer loop. How did you determin that the calls of the functions are in a 'wrong order'?

Comment: @Japhei I ran the debugger and set breakpoints of all the methods and the first one  executed is cursoAlumnoView.listarEntrega().

Comment: can you check again? Maybe put some sysouts in the beginning of each method. Are there some problems with the output of this website? If there is indeed some problem with the order of this website can you provide the excact order this methods are being executed? Seems to me like the inner for loops have always the same output.